# Unable print string from decrypt Base64 data in Swift

Tags: swift, aes, encode

I've checked many post and ask ChatGPT, but still struggling.

The input data is an encrypted Base64 String file with AES128 standard, and exported from Java:

```
public static String encrypt(String text) {
        try {
            byte[] TextByte = encryptAES(
                    IvAES.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    , keyAES.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                    , text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            );
            return TextByte != null ? Base64.encodeToString(TextByte, Base64.DEFAULT) : null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.error(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here's my code, however, always get "unable turn decryptedData to string" message.

I guess the issue may related with this block, since I already encode data to String with utf8 format, so it looks like I encode same data again?

`guard let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)`

```
//UIDocumentPickerDelegate
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]) {
    if let selectedFileURL = urls.first  {
        if let data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: selectedFileURL.path) {
            
            guard let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("unable turn data into string")
                return
            }
            print("dataStr: \(dataStr)")

            guard let encrypted = Data(base64Encoded: dataStr,options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
                print("unable decode")
                return
            }
            
            let decryptedData = AESCrypt.testCrypt(data:encrypted, operation: .Decrypt)
            print("decryptedData: \(decryptedData)")//4944 bytes
            
            if let decodedStr = String(data: decryptedData, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("decoded: \(decodedStr)")
            } else {
                print("unable turn decryptedData to string")//**Ended here**
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the AES library, which in charge with encryption:

```
struct AESCrypt {
    private let key: Data
    private var ivSize: Int = kCCBlockSizeAES128
    private let options: CCOptions = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
    static let keyData = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    init(key: Data) throws {
        guard key.count == kCCKeySizeAES256 else {
            throw Error.invaildKeySize
        }
        self.key = key
    }
}

extension AESCrypt {
    enum EncrptyOperation {
        case Encrypt
        case Decrypt
    }
    func encrypt(_ string: String) throws -> Data {
        let data = Data(string.utf8)
        return try encrypt(string)
    }
    
    static func testCrypt(data: Data, operation: EncrptyOperation) -> Data {

        let cryptLength = data.count + kCCBlockSizeAES128

        var cryptOperation: CCOperation
        var cryptData = Data(count: cryptLength)
        
        let keyLength = kCCKeySizeAES128

        let options = CCOptions(kCCOptionPKCS7Padding)
        let keyData = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvabc".data(using: .utf8)!
        let ivData = "appnameivdata".data(using: .utf8)!

        switch operation {
        case .Encrypt:
            cryptOperation = CCOperation(kCCEncrypt)
            break
        case .Decrypt:
            cryptOperation = CCOperation(kCCDecrypt)
            break
        }

        var numberBytesEncrypted: size_t = 0
        let cryptStatus = cryptData.withUnsafeMutableBytes { cryptBytes in
            data.withUnsafeBytes { dataBytes in
                ivData.withUnsafeBytes { ivBytes in
                    keyData.withUnsafeBytes { keyBytes in
                        CCCrypt(cryptOperation,
                                CCAlgorithm(kCCAlgorithmAES128), options,
                                keyBytes,//key: UnsafeRawPointer!
                                keyLength,
                                ivBytes,
                                dataBytes,
                                data.count,
                                cryptBytes,
                                cryptLength,
                                &numberBytesEncrypted)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        if UInt32(cryptStatus) == UInt32(kCCSuccess) { // if status is success
            cryptData.removeSubrange(numberBytesEncrypted..<cryptData.count)
        } else {
            print("error: \(cryptStatus)")
        }
        return cryptData
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `encryptAES()`? Which library are `AESCrypt` and `doCrypt()` from? Post an executable code and test data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: selectedFileURL) else {
   print("unable to get data")
   return
}

guard let dataStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
   print("unable turn data into string")
   return
}
```

and see if this works or not

Comment: Can you please update your answer with an explanation of how this applies to the question? This code basically replicates part of what the OP is already doing in their code.